# In Java, whenever I run my code, my txt file gets wiped

Tags: java, file-io, filewriter

Whenever I run my code, the inv.txt file changes from having 25 lines of the character 1 to nothing, could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
PS the main class includes inventory.addItem();

```
 public class inventory {
File inventory = new File("Resources/inv.txt");
File db = new File("Resources/db.txt");
FileWriter write;
StringBuilder writethis;

public void addItem(int item, int slot){
    int i;
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(inventory);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        write = new FileWriter(inventory);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(i = 1; i < slot; i++)writethis.append(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println(writethis.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Uhm, where do you use `db` here?

Comment: @fge nowhere in this method, I'm using it in a different method.

Answer (score 2):

Use `write = new FileWriter(inventory, true);`

It will append data to existing file. See the documentation on `FileWriter` Constructor for further details.

Comment: Thats not it, seeing as I don't want it to append, and I also don't even try to write to the file in my code.

Comment: @drdavehere Yes, but as soon as it hits that line it will clear the file. Whether or not it writes to it.

Comment: @imtheman Really? Thanks! I guess I'll just put that part of the code after I've read the file, etc.

Comment: Actually when you call `new FileWriter(inventory);` a new empty file is created. `new FileWriter(inventory, true);` will prevent your program from creating a new file.

Comment: @drdavehere That is a good idea. Also, make sure you close the Scanner before you start writing.

Comment: Ok, but then, won't it just append to the file? I want it to replace the file with writethis.toString(); (Not something I've written in the code)

Comment: @drdavehere Yes, it will append. I recommend you just create the `FileWriter` after you get all of the data.

Comment: You should really consider using the new API; for instance, `Files.newBufferedWriter()`. With the correct options, you will select to append to the file, create it if it doesn't exist, etc. Ditch the old file API.